# How do I create a PDF, invoke a download of it, then delete it?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, pdf, download

So I have a controller that's like

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult HtmlToPdf ( string html, Guid pid )
    {

            PdfDocument D = new PdfDocument();
           // ... build document
            string filename = "summary_" + pid.ToString() + ".pdf";
            D.Save(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Dumps"), filename));
            return Json(new { filename = filename });
    }
```

which then `window.open`s that file on the client side. The problem is that these PDFs are over 1 MB and I don't want to reach my Azure memory limit. Other than a quick-and-dirty solution like setting a timer that deletes the file after a certain amount of time, what solutions are there for me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use two different tools in conjunction with each other, first is the `Azure Blob Storage containers`. Upload the PDF's to the containers, return the URL of the PDF to your user.

The other tool is called `Azure WebJobs`, they're basically tasks that run in the background which you can set up on a schedule and use to delete older PDFs that you uploaded earlier.

---

**Resources**

- [Run Background tasks with WebJobs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/)
- [Get started with Azure Blob storage using .NET](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/)